# Angular 7 routes concat results in compile error

Tags: angular, typescript, concatenation

First - FYI, the routing module is set to:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(ALL_ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Placing all routes in 1 array named: 'ALL_ROUTES' and passing the array to the AppRoutingModule - imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(ALL_ROUTES)], works fine:

```
export const ALL_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {path: 'route1', component: FirstComponent},
  {path: 'route2', component: SecondComponent},
  {path: 'route3', component: ThirdComponent},
  {path: 'route4', component: FourthComponent}
];
```

So, the above code works fine.
However, if we have 2 arrays and concat them like this:

```
export const ROUTES1: Routes = [
  {path: 'route1', component: FirstComponent},
  {path: 'route2', component: SecondComponent}
];

export const ROUTES2: Routes = [
  {path: 'route3', component: ThirdComponent},
  {path: 'route4', component: FourthComponent}
];

export const ALL_ROUTES: Routes = ROUTES1.concat(ROUTES2);
```

we get a compilation error:

```
ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of undefined
```

Couple of similar questions have been asked here, but no resolution for this problem. Is there a possible solution? Possibly an explanation of what is going on?

Comment: Try maybe something like `export const ALL_ROUTES: Routes = [...ROUTES1, ...ROUTES2];`

Comment: That appears to be working. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

For those who are searching for posts with answers - as suggested above by Danil, this seams to be working. Please post comments if any potential issues.

```
export const ALL_ROUTES: Routes =
    [
      ...ROUTES1,
      ...ROUTES2
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try that too.

```
const supportedGames: Route[] = [
    {
        path: "pubg",
        component: LoginComponent
    }
];

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: LoginComponent,
    },
    {
        path: "login",
        component: LoginComponent,
    },
    {
        path: "main",
        component: MainViewComponent,
        children: ([
            {
                path: "game-list",
                component: GameListComponent,
            }
        ] as Route[]).concat(supportedGames)
    },
    {
        path: "**",
        redirectTo: ""
    }
];
```